# How do I format a cell to be in alternative currency without decimals in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am really scratching my head, but it seems like this is not possible in Google Spreadsheets. I want to format a number cell in kroner without any decimals. All I get is "kr 38,434.00" I want this number without any decimals. Could it really be that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the cell with the number.
2. Click the number format button on the toolbar.
3. Select the decimal-less currency format.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no decimal-less currency format for kr. I can find it for Dollars, though.

Comment: If you don't see different currency formats, click on `File -> Spreadhseet settings` and change the locale to `United States`.

Comment: Hey! I changed the locale to "Denmark" and kr. showed up as a currency-less option in the list. Thanks!

Comment: I meant, "decimal-less option".

Answer (score 2):

In [Google New Sheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068) - being rolled out in April 2014, setting currencies and decimals are split, as you can set the currency first (now hidden at **Format** -> **Number** -> **More Formats** -> **More currencies**) and then use the Decrease/Increase buttons to change the decimals:

[image]

Note that I found a bug in that if you decrease decimals on multiple cells, then they will all be reset to the currency of the first cell - so select each currency on its own.

It is not as of 2014-04 possible to 'upgrade' existing sheets to the 'New sheets' as far as I know.